# How to get the wrapper element created with "wrapAll()"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

Consider the following code: (live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dE9HV/1/))

```js
$(function() {
  var wrapper = $("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
  $(".a").wrapAll(wrapper);
  wrapper.css("border", "5px solid black"); // Doesn't work
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">Hello</div>
<div class="a">Stack</div>
<div class="a">Overflow</div>
```

What would be the right way to get the created wrapper and change its attributes ?

**Note:** There are other `.wrapper` elements in the DOM, so this won't work:

```
$(".wrapper").css("border", "5px solid black");
```

I don't want to give a unique `id` to the created wrapper either.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since you just wrapped the elements, you can use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to obtain the newly inserted wrappers:

```
$(".a").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'></div>")
       .parent().css("border", "5px solid black");
```

Comment: @Matthew, `wrapAll()` returns the wrapped element. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2e2WL/), it will say `DIV` and not `P`.

Comment: It would be nice to have a way to more robustly capture the resulting wrapper...using parent only goes one level up, but if someone came in and added a nested div as a wrapper (e.g. `<div class="wrapper-outer"><div class="wrapper-inner"></div></div>`), then parent will not get the outermost wrapper, as is most likely expected.

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery object stored in `wrapper` gets cloned when `wrapAll` gets called, so you cannot affect the `.wrappers` which have been inserted into the DOM by manipulating `wrapper`, you need to select them from the document.

Comment: +1 for explaining how `wrapAll()` works, though it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Misha - I thought Frederic had already done that, just wanted to add a point.

Comment: @karim79 probably better to do that as a comment to the original answer

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function() {
    var wrapper = $("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
    var wrapped = $(".a").wrapAll(wrapper);
    wrapped.css("border", "5px solid black");
});
```